# Python compiler that can compile a program that utilises Pillow/PIL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, python-imaging-library

I've written a program that utilises the [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io) module (a [PIL](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/overview.htm) fork).
I would like to compile the finished program to an .exe for distribution.
I have tried compiling the program with both [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) and [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net), however neither of these seem to support the compilation of a program that utilises this external module.

Does anyone know of any other Python compilers that support the compilation of a program that utilises the Pillow module?

Thank you

Comment: Have you heard of Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Anaconda is your best bet.

Anaconda is a complete package of all python programming essentials. It also has your much needed `pillow` (or the so called python imaging library) built-in.

It comes with certain other python packages built-in and ready-to-use such as `numpy`, `pandas`, `scipy`, `matplotlib`, and `IPython`.

It also has an easy-to-use IDE namely `Spyder`, which is the playground. You get to do all your coding here. `Spyder` is just like any other text editor but with more functionality an ease of access.

If your looking out for more options in image processing, Anaconda also comes with `scikit-image` or `skmage` (also built-in)

In case you want to install OpenCV on your machine, it can be easily done using the Anaconda command prompt using this command:

`conda install -c menpo opencv=3.0.0`

Visit the website [HERE](https://docs.continuum.io/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How easy is it to compile a .py file to an .exe file using Anaconda?

Comment: Sorry I completely misread your question. I presumed you were unable to work with `pillow`. To answer your question you could try `cx_Freeze`

Comment: Another option is using `py2exe`, provided you use only Python version 3.3 or higher. :D

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't very clear, I'll make sure to give both of those a try. Thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to have another attempt at compiling my program using Pyinstaller.
Pyinstaller already worked with Pillow, however it ran into problems with programs that utilised Tix.

After a lot of trial and error, I managed to create a solution based on [a comment on github](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1660#issuecomment-204208566).

[My solution](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1660#issuecomment-279111235).